# 2 Classes, Sorting into ArrayList to Descending order

Tags: java, arraylist, comparator

I have one class (Card) which declares enums for playing cards (suit and rank). The second class (Deck) creates the deck from the enums, shuffles them and inserts them into an ArrayList.

In the first class i have this class/method:

```
       public static abstract class descendingCards implements Comparator{
           public static ArrayList<Card> sortDescending(ArrayList<Card> cardList){
               Comparator<Card> c = Collections.reverseOrder();
               Collections.sort(cardList, c);
               return cardList;
    }
}
```

My main method class contains this:

```
    System.out.print(Deck.newDeck());
    System.out.print("After Sorting to desending: " + "\n");
    System.out.print(Card.descendingCards.sortDescending(Deck.newDeck()));
```

Initially i was creating the deck in the first class and the method worked fine. Since i have moved the deck creation to the second class, i think the method only returns an empty ArrayList. I'm slightly confused. I'm sure its something small I'm overlooking. Any help would be appreciated. Thanks.

Comment: Can you paste your newDeck() method as well?

Comment: please show us the rest of the code...

Comment: Ok i've fixed it. I realised it was returning the empty ArrayList it just created. I simply added the double For-Loop from the Constructor inside the newDeck method and now they work again. Silly moment. Haha Thanks anyway people :)

Comment: @qwertyRocker If you've fixed your own problem, please post the solution as an answer and accept your own answer so that it is clear the problem is solved.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The solution is quite simple you are not calling the **Deck** constructor you are just creating an empty ArrayList. The Deck is filled by the constructor and since you are not calling the constructor the deck remains empty.

Comment: Yep, i literally just realised this. I was having a dumb moment. Problem solved. Thanks guys :)